# Calculating CVaR as indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to wrap my head conceptually around VaR, and CVaR. For this purpose, I thought I could write a simple indicator that displays the CVaR of the current asset as a line graph. Obviously, all calculations are then based on the returns of the asset itself, which is fine, just to understand the concept.

What I'm having trouble with is trying to find the right way of sorting the returns, and accessing them. I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://youtube.com/watch?v=2QJykxUNb6I). What I got from the video is that the method he uses is:

1. Calculate the returns.
2. Sort the returns in ascending order, and create a rank.
3. Calculate VaR by checking which return is at the 95th percent rank, also take note of its index.
4. Calculate the average of 95th return to the worst return by using the index noted before.

I thought using the `percentrank` functions would help here, but this did not lead to a solution. Now I'm trying to put the returns into an array, and then use the array to do all the calculations. I'm not good at using arrays.

What I seek is help with why this does not work, and where my thinking isn't correct. If I mislabeled something, please also let me know, as it would greatly help me to better understand this relatively advanced topic.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
//@version=5
indicator("CVaR", overlay=false)

lookback = 300
confidence_level = input.float(title="Confidence Level", defval=0.95)

returns = close / close[1] - 1

// This does not work
// number = quantile_level * lookback
// value_at_risk = ta.percentrank(returns, int(number))
// conditional_value_at_risk = (1/value_at_risk) * math.sum(returns, ta.percentrank(returns, number))

// This could work
returns_array = array.from(returns)
array.sort(returns_array, order.ascending)
rank = int(lookback * quantile_level)
value_at_risk = array.get(returns_array, rank)

// Plot the CVaR
plot(cvar, title="CVaR", color=color.red) // gives an out of bounds error, obviously.
```